# Create virtualenv in existing directory without creating a "local" directory

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm trying something simple.  I clone a repository and then I want to create a virtualenv in it:

```
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/neves/repo site
virtualenv site
```

When I run the command to create a Python virtualenv in an exiting project, a directory named *local* is created.  All the contents of the "site" dir are copied to this local dir. I don't want this behaviour.  Am I doing something wrong? How do I create a virtualenv without creating this *local* dir?

I'm using virtualenv 1.10.1

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Not sure if it is still helpful, but you can do this.

```
virtualenv .
```

Install was fine with me.

Comment: That's just what I wanted. To create a virtualenv using current directory's name :) Thanks!

Comment: Welcome @NikitaHismatov

Comment: I want also confirm that those command worked for me in W7 from a proxy server(as instead for pip one need to include the --proxy yourproxyadressparameters)

Comment: hi @CarmineTambascia an upvote on my answer is always appreciated ;)

Comment: @Andy actually I have faced the state that on creating that virtual env with that command, it used the based Python interpreter, but unfortunately it does not see packages I have installed in the virtual env itself(I noticed it as Pycharm is giving me "not found reference for things like django.db, but django it's been installed in the Virtualenv. I was looking at the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145656/unresolved-reference-django-in-pycharm but isn't been installed any Interpreter into the virtual Env.

Comment: Any suggestions?Does maybe on creating the env it's better specify the Python Interpreter explicitly?

Comment: Actually I am just noticing that inside the Scripts folder in the env there is a valid python.exe . Then issue sorted

Comment: This also worked with the new version `venv` :  `python3 -m venv .`

Answer (score 4):

This just happens on some platforms (like Ubuntu) and is necessary because a virtualenv *imitates* the machine's installation, and `local` is part of that. Just add it to your SCM's ignore facility (e.g. `.gitignore`).

Comment: Excuse me, but I didn't understand why it is necessary to have a copy of everything there. I  just delete it. It  is just an annoyance, but maybe it is a hint that  I'm not doing something right.

Comment: Looks like `pyvenv` creates less directories then vertualenv:
```bin/  include/    lib/        pyvenv.cfg```

Comment: You're free to delete it. As jhermann mentioned, it tries to imitate the Ubuntu approach of keeping Python-related libraries and modules in `~/.local`, for example if you installed them using `pip` and the `--user` argument.