# Django - Failed to import a models file from another app

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to import a model into some app from another app, but it throws an error.

[image]

```
from django.db import models
from ..book.models import Book


class Cart:
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

But if I do:

```
from django.db import models
from book.models import Book


class Cart:
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

PyCharm will be complaining. It says "Unsolved reference book".

This won't work as well:

```
from django.db import models
from shop.book.models import Book


class Cart:
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shop.book'
```

Comment: Can you add your project structure(tree structure) in the question?

Comment: fix the project root on. Pycharm > Preferences > Project > Project Structure > Add content root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would work fine when you use the below. It is a pycharm issue and you can solve the pycharm issue by doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43455858/4881398)

```
from django.db import models
from book.models import Book 
class Cart:
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try importing with a function.
`def make_it_im_port(self):
import(x)`
Then call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `book` exists as an app in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list within `settings.py`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it exists in INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py

Comment: Does `Book` exist as a class in `book/models.py`?

Comment: Also, make sure your PyCharm project interpreter is using the Python binary located in the virtualenv you set up.

Comment: Does the version of Python matter? I'm using Python 3.7

Comment: @Jinx nope, just the fact that the Project Interpreter is pointing to one of the python binaries in `~/PycharmProjects/eBookstore/venv/bin/`

Comment: Try the solutions offered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm