# Can't import anything from django

Tags: python, django

I'm having problems with importing stuff from Django.
I'm entirely new to python and I'm following a tutorial where I'm taught how to make my first Django project (I'm using Pycharm by the way).
The problem I'm encountering is when I try to import something from Django it says `Unresolved reference 'django'`.

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
```

This case only shows the red squiggly line under the two `HttpResponse`, and `render`.

Any help would be appreciated, I have tried searching on google, but I couldn't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you install django?  It's not built in.  `pip install django`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unresolved reference: 'django' error in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145656/unresolved-reference-django-error-in-pycharm)

Comment: Thanks I think this is my problem, but there isn't very specific information about how you then add the package, can you help me with that?

Comment: I gave you the command.  Once you install it, it is available.

Comment: oh well then that's not my problem because I already did that and it just says "Requirement already satisfied"

Comment: Have you marked root folder of project as 'Sources root' (as it is said in upper question)? You need to go to settings/Project/Project Structure. Then mark a folder with your app code as 'sources' (blue color).